# nodejs raspberry serialport incorrect data

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-serialport

I want to parse serial data with nodeJs v0.12.6 on Raspberry Pi 1.

Data is correct with cat but scrambled with nodeJs (serialPort module)

## data OK with cat

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 1200 sane evenp parenb cs7 -crtscts
cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

gives

```
MOTDETAT 000000 B

ADCO XXXXXXXXXXX>
OPTARIF HC.. <
ISOUSC 30 9
HCHC 042116615  
HCHP 034246387 8
PTEC HP..  
IINST 001 X
IMAX 009 H
HHPHC C .
MOTDETAT 000000 B

ADCO XXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

[result with CR-ETX-STX-LF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkNCh.jpg)
where block separator is CR-ETX-STX-LF

## 2. data incorrect with nodeJs

My nodeJs server

```
var serialPort = new serialport.SerialPort('/dev/ttyAMA0', {
    baudrate: 1200,
    dataBits: 7,
    parity: 'even',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl :true,      
    //CR-ETX-STX-BR
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline(String.fromCharCode(13,3,2,10))
});

serialPort.on('data', function(data) {      
    console.log("data="+data);
});
```

Result is

```
ADCO 0PTARIF H 9
2116615 
HCHP 031
..  
01 X
9 H
 .
T 000000
ADCO 0218 >
OC.. <
```

[result with separators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6wbS.jpg)

All data are scrambled, why ?

Seems like I receive 8 bytes, then 8 bytes lost, then 8 bytes received, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like tty was not well configured.
With

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 1200 sane parenb -parodd cs7 -isig -icrnl -crtscts -icanon
```

serialPort is now working.

The error was that I relied on what I saw with cat /dev/ttyAMA0. But it shows only printable characters and not really data which comes.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer to the question, why bytes are missing, but it's a solution to retrieve all data.

I use fs module.

Note : separators are ETX and STX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX)

```
fs = require('fs');
inp = fs.createReadStream(port);
inp.setEncoding('utf8');
var inputtext = "";
var start = false;
var end = false;
var charSTX = String.fromCharCode(2);
var charETX = String.fromCharCode(3);
inp.on('data', function (data) {
    var indexOfCharSTX = data.indexOf(charSTX);
    if(!start){
        if(indexOfCharSTX!=-1){
            start = true;
            end   = false;
            inputtext = '';
            //after STX and next LF
            data  = data.substr(indexOfCharSTX+2, data.length);
        }else{
            // waiting next data for start character
            return;
        }
    }

    var indexOfCharETX = data.indexOf(charETX);
    if(indexOfCharETX!=-1){
        //before ETX and previous CR
        data = data.substr(0, indexOfCharETX-1);
        end = true;
    }

    inputtext+=data;

    if(end){
        //do something with inputtext here
        start = false;
        end   = false;
        inputtext = '';
    }
});
```